# carouselExampleIndicators Error in angular 4

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, carousel

I have crated carousel in my page by using following code

```
<div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://d1.awsstatic.com/webteam/homepage/heroes/videos/Site-Merch_reInvent-Keynote_Hero-Video-Poster.00baa02675e98818eec00a087f6ea87aecedfada.jpg"
                alt="first slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://d1.awsstatic.com/webteam/homepage/heroes/overlay-art/Site-Merch_PAC-SageMaker_Hero-Art.8aef321eaf4ab9bd490ff66a1cd8981b889373d0.png"
                alt="Second slide">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://d1.awsstatic.com/webteam/homepage/heroes/overlay-art/Site-Merch_What-is-AWS_Hero-Art.d92a5ae5daf0c0735f49b06814bee7a07742ba20.png"
                alt="Third slide">
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

by using following [Link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/).
But in the page images are showing but it is not `scrolling auto` and if try to to click on arrows it is showing error in the console

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'carouselExampleIndicators'
>   Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'carouselExampleIndicators'

I checked `bootstrap version` that is `v4`

I don't know whats going wring the code. could any one please let me and what it causing error

Answer (score 0):

You problem is that you are using functionality that can not be used in Angular, bootstrap have hiw own angular-way library, and here is your carousel [here](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples)

Same with that, angular sees something like this `#carouselExampleIndicators` ang thinks that it is a route that you need to use, so it falls with an Error. So my advice is to use bootstrap components that written for angular and vice versa.